# align image to a column of text while keeping it responsive

Tags: css, wordpress, text-alignment

I am trying to code a class schedule in `Wordpress`. I have attached a picture of a mock up to better illustrate what I am trying to achieve.

Mock Up below here:

[image]

The text div keeps either going under the thumb div or wraps around it and my column is lost.

Also, when going into responsive mode, the divs do not align one under each other, but stack up one on top of the other. I am trying to have the thumb image with a column of text next to it just like in the picture and have it scale nicely into small screens.

Any ideas how this could be accomplished? Is it even possible? Thank you so much in advance.

Here is the code:

```
#text {
width: 33%;
align: left;
clear: both;
}

#thumb {
width: 33%;
align: left;
}

<div id ="thumb"><img src=“---" /></div>
<div id=“text”>NAME OF FIRST CLASS
</div>
```

Comment: Please share your code so we can see what you have so far. When you do that, there will be no need for explaining what you did in the question itself

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend using Flexbox for this, if you think most of your users will be Win10 or any other non-Windows OS* ([source](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex)). Chris Coyier has a great [article](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) on CSS Tricks about how to use the Flexbox module that you should totally check out too!

Basically, your HTML for each class is probably structured somewhat like this already:

```
<article class="class">
  <img alt="" class="class__image" src="" />
  <div class="class__info">
    <h2 class="class__title">Title</h2>
    <p class="class__description">Description</p>
    <div class="schedule class__schedule">
      <h3 class="schedule__title">Dates</h3>
      <div class="event schedule__event">
        <div class="event__info">
          <p class="event__date-time">Date, Time</p>
          <p class="event__location">Location</p>
        </div>
        <div class="event__action">
          <button class="event__register">Register</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      ...
```

So your new CSS will look something like this:

```
.class {
  display: flex;       /* 1 */
}
.class__image {
  width: 20%;
}
.class__info {
  flex-grow: 1;        /* 2 */
}
.schedule__event {
  align-items: center; /* 3 */
  display: flex;
}
.event__info {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.event__action {
  width: 45%;
}
```

1. This tells the browser we're going to use Flexbox in this element
2. This essentially says "take up all remaining space", meaning in the future you can change the image width and not need to do any math to figure out the resulting size for the info
3. This makes your Register button line up vertically in the middle of the text to its left

I'm a little confused about what you want to have happen at smaller screen sizes, but Flexbox won't wrap by default. If you want to change that, add something like the following to your CSS:

```
@media all and (max-width: 600px) {
  .class,
  .schedule__event {
    flex-direction: column;  /* 4 */
    justify-content: center; /* 5 */
  }
```

4. This changes the direction in which the child elements appear from horizontally left-to-right to vertically top-to-bottom
5. This aligns the child elements to be centered horizontally

And that should about do it in terms of page layout!

---

* If you'd like, you can find a Flexbox polyfill to get the functionality on some older versions of IE :)

Comment: Thank you! I am going to try what you suggested. I am new to this so it takes me a while :-)

Answer (score 0):

**Last Updated on July 12, 2016**

Along with it you need to add media queries to target mobile.

When the site is viewed in less than 320px screens. `#text` and `#thumb` **float** property is set to **none** and **width** is increased from **33%** to **100%**. To increase the spacing between two elements(`#text`, `#thumb`) we have added **margin-bottom** of **10px** to the `#thumb`

```
@media all and (max-width:320px){
  #text{ float:none; width:100%; }
  #thumb { float:none; width:100%;margin-bottom:10px; }
}
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tympaaz/0mdnmjgu/)**

---

***UPDATE***

You are missing few things. In order to left align elements you need to use **float** since there is no css property with name **align**.

Since we are floating elements we need to make sure we are wrapping those two divs (`.thumb`,`.text`) within another div ( `.post` or some other class ) and add '.clearfix' class to it.

'.clearfix' does the same thing as `clear:both` css property

```
<div class="post clearfix">
<div id ="thumb">
<img src=“---" />
</div>

<div id=“text”>
NAME OF FIRST CLASS The Big Oxmox advised her not to do so, because there were thousands of bad Commas, wild Question Marks and devious Semikoli, but the Little Blind Text didn’t listen. She packed her seven versalia, put her initial into the belt and made herself on the way. Aug 1 - 2, 9AM - 5PM Salt Lake City, UT
</div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
 .clearfix:after{visibility:hidden;display:block;font-size:0;content:" ";clear:both;height:0;}
    .clearfix{display:inline-block;clear:both;}
    * html .clearfix{height:1%;}
    .clearfix{display:block;}

.post { width:100%; }
#text { width: 33%; float: left;} 
#thumb { width: 33%; float: left; }
```

---

If you can show us the code it will be helpful and will take us less time to solve the issue.

Based on the details you gave. It can happen if you are not adding `.clearfix` class to the parent div

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent-div clearfix">
   <div class="image">
   </div>

   <div class="text">
   </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.clearfix:after{visibility:hidden;display:block;font-size:0;content:" ";clear:both;height:0;}
.clearfix{display:inline-block;clear:both;}
* html .clearfix{height:1%;}
.clearfix{display:block;}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Just added the code to the main post. I am very new here. Thank you so much for responding!

Comment: Thank you so much! I have coded exactly like you said. The text column is now displayed next to the thumb. However when scaling down to mobile view, the divs do not stack up one under another. They remain in 2 columns making the text unreadable since each word takes up a line. Any ideas?

Comment: @typaaz I have finally got it to work and styled as needed thanks to you. I am having one issue with the register button though. I started a new thread here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38414804/align-button-to-text-vertically-with-float If you're up for it, could you look at it please. Thank you!

Comment: @lara Sure i will have a look at it after reaching home. Can you mark the answer on this thread if it really helped you.

Comment: I cant mark anything because I don't have enough authority. I tried marking it! It won't let me.